# Pygame sprite object not callable after pygame.sprite.Group()

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, sprite

I have recently started using **pygame.sprite.Sprite** and **sprite.Group()** classes in pygame and I have run into a problem that once my sprites are grouped I can no longer initialize a new class instance and instead raise "TypeError: 'NPC' object is not callable". Here is my code (cut down for succinctness);

```
class NPC(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_x, start_y, image):...
npc_pop=pygame.sprite.Group()
locations=[(100,200), (300,300), (150,200)]
def spawn_NPC(x, y):
    image_SS = ss.image_at(rando(), colorkey=(255, 0, 128)) #random image from sprite-sheet
    new_guy = NPC(x, y, image_SS)
    npc_pop.add(new_guy)
for c in locations:
    spawn_NPC(c[0],c[1])
while gameLoop == True:
    ....
    npc_pop.draw(screen)
    if len(npc_pop) < 2:
        spawn_NPC(100,100)
```

Without going into too much detail about the NPC class, before the game loop NPC behaves as a class and fills the sprite container npc_pop without issues. However the next instance(s) of NPC class are called as a function raising an error on the last line that traces back to spawn_NPC(). Why?

I read this thread [Getting an Error Trying to Create an Object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407655/getting-an-error-trying-to-create-an-object-in-python) and realize grouping sprites alters the class somehow but I still don't fully understand the logic.

Comment: you have wrong indentions so we can't read your code. Add 4 spaces before every line before you put code on SO.

Comment: always add full error message. there is not only message but also line which makes problem, etc.

Comment: problem described in link have nothing to do with group. For example you can set `print = "Hello World"` and then every `print(some_text)` will give you error `'str' object is not callable` because now `print` is not function but variable which keeps value `"Hello World"` and now `print(some_text)` means `"Hello World"(some_text)` - so you have to find in code line similar to `NPC = ...` or `some_NCP_object = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code is more clear, I solved my problem by writing a dedicated module for my NPC sprite class and building a class generator.

```
    import walk #NPC class now imported from a module
    @classmethod
    def spawnNPC(self, list):
    for c in list:
        image_SS = ss.image_at(rando(), colorkey=(255, 0, 128))
        new_guy = walk.NPC(c[0],c[1],image_SS)
        print type(new_guy), "googly"
        new_guy.add(npc_pop)

    #generate NPC instances at multiple locations before game start
    MiniSpawn = type("MiniSpawn", (object,), {"spawnNPC":spawnNPC})
    locations = [(333, 200), (300, 300), (200, 200), (50, 50)]
    MiniSpawn.spawnNPC(locations)

    #Generate new NPC instances in the game loop
    if started == 1 and len(npc_mov) < 2:
        MiniSpawn.spawnNPC([(200,300)])
```